# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in cloud9 ide

Tags: node.js, sails.js, cloud9-ide

I am running a sailsJS project on Cloud9.io and using mysql.here are my configurations.

**In config/local.js**

```
port: process.env.PORT,
host: process.env.IP
```

**In config/connection.js**

```
mysqlDB:{
  adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  database: 'custom',
  user:'myname',
  password:'',
  supportBigNumbers:true, //true/false
  module    : 'sails-mysql',
  debug:['ComQueryPacket'], //false or array of node-mysql debug options
  trace:true //true/false
```

}

it gives me this error

```
{ [Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'     
(using password: NO)]
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
errno: 1045,
sqlState: '28000',
fatal: true }
```

i can't understand why it is saying user@localhost  while i am expecting it as myname@localhost

thanx for helping me here.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve it by correct the SQL config:

```
 var config = {
    host    :'127.0.0.1',
    user    :'root',
    password:'root',
    port    :'3306',
    database:'new_schema'
}
module.exports =  config;
```

If you have an incorrect config you will get error. And if you haven't added the last line `"module.exports =  config;"`, you will also get `error`.

I faced the second case! [May help you~`]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Cloud9's MySQL documentation page [here](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/setting-up-mysql): https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/setting-up-mysql for some information regarding MySQL connection params.

The following *should* work:

```
mysqlDB:{
 adapter: 'sails-mysql',
 host: process.env.IP,
 database: 'custom',
 user: process.env.C9_USER,
 password:'',
 supportBigNumbers:true, //true/false
 module    : 'sails-mysql',
 debug:['ComQueryPacket'], //false or array of node-mysql debug options
 trace:true //true/false
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can echo the respective environment variables using `echo $IP` or `echo $C9_USER` and try pasting the output within your connection.js file.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by your_password;
```

using this on mysql database query worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**THE ERROR**

> if this code is executed : code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
> errno: 1045,
> sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
> sqlState: '28000',
> fatal: true

**ANSWER**

Just create a new User in the XAMMP in useraccounts,enter the credentials that you have created from (useraccounts in XAMMP) in the (.env) file.

you can also type the following code in this SQL manner:

```sql
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '***';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**THE PROBLEM**

```
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
errno: 1045,
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
sqlState: '28000',
fatal: true;
```

**THE ANSWER**
u should enter correct credentials in the `.env` file or:

just include
`require('dotenv').config();` IN the working file

*OR*
grant all permissions like DELETE, SELECT  to the user u have created previously

Answer (score 0):

you need to require (.env) file.

## require('dotenv').config()

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that you added port key in the config

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'node-complete',
    password: '2002',
    port: 5500
});

module.exports = pool.promise();
```